# Problem with axis order in WFS with QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wfs

I'm attempting to make use of some data from the Scottish Government's WFS server. But there is an axis order issue, I just want to check that it isn't something I've done before I raise an issue with my MSP (or the server admin).

[image]

In the above image the "blue" data is from the [ScotGov WMS server](https://maps.gov.scot/server/services/ScotGov/PeopleSociety/MapServer/WMSServer?) while the weird purple data is from [their WFS server](https://maps.gov.scot/server/services/ScotGov/PeopleSociety/MapServer/WFSServer?). As you will notice not only are the axes swapped (and ticking the invert axis button in QGis seems not to help) but the eastings (or vertical in this data) is reversed too.

Just axis swapping I could live with (though since I [request the data in 27700](https://maps.gov.scot/server/services/ScotGov/PeopleSociety/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=SOC:SIMD2020&STARTINDEX=4000&MAXFEATURES=1000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700&BBOX=110690.27611891887499951,422163.53999999997904524,503028.92537297296803445,760702.02000000001862645,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700) I don't understand it) but reversing an axis too is very strange.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

## Update

Even with the swap axis and/or ignore axis order set I still don't get the right position

[image]

Comment: Inverting the axis works for me in QGIS 3.28 ; but the service is surely wrong if it's sending out data with the wrong axis order.  WMS/WFS version shouldn't affect axis order for EPSG:27700.

Answer (score 3):

Swapping X and Y did the trick for me (under 3.28). Both using the tool, and checking the box when loading the WFS.

Maybe you didn't check the box properly, or marked the wrong box?

[image]